# When adding struts-html.tld to jsp file occurs Error

Tags: java, jsp, server, struts, stack-overflow

I am migrating some code over to a new server which uses OpenJDK version 1.8. My code will run if I don't have 
 taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html
at the top of the file but I need this for a feature on my page.

It works fine with:

```java
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-nested.tld" prefix="nested" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/c.tld" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/fn.tld" prefix="fn" %>
```

When I add `<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html" %>` at the top **I get the error:**
`message org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError`

Description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:561)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:462)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Let me know if anyone has an idea of where my problem could be. I added the below code snippet showing an instance where the error is occurring:

```js
 <tr>
                                   <td class="title">User Name:</td>
                                   <td class="data">

                                        <html:text property="username" maxlength="32" size="20" />
                                        <logic:messagesPresent message="true">
                                                <span class="error">
                                                        <html:messages property="username" id="errorMsg" message="true">
                                                                <bean:write name="errorMsg"/>
                                                        </html:messages>
                                                </span>
                                        </logic:messagesPresent>
                                        <logic:messagesPresent>
                                                <span class="error">
                                                        <html:messages property="username" id="errorMsg">
                                                                <bean:write name="errorMsg"/>
                                                        </html:messages>
                                                </span>
                                        </logic:messagesPresent>

                                   </td>
                                </tr>
```

Comment: What feature on the page do you need the TLD for? That hasn't been required for like a decade.

Comment: It looks like its used for two text boxes and a button.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking of the web.xml tld, you still need it on the page. Without knowing anything about the code there's no way to help, though.

Comment: The code is so massive that I am not sure what to present here... I thought maybe someone would have an idea.

Comment: If a JSP page is that big you have additional issues. Just adding a TLD doesn't affect the code (other than making the related tags actually compilable). It's more likely there's something on the page that causes the SO; the complete stack trace should be able to help pinpoint where. It's *possible* there's an incompatibility with Java 1.8, especially if it's an early version of S1.

Comment: I added some code showing where the error is occurring. I am hoping its not a compatibility issue with Java 1.8... Upgrading this to struts 2 would be a nightmare.

Comment: Eliminate each html tag and introduce them back one at a time. Then look at the underlying data/implementation being used as the tag's properties and the related action form. This is basic debugging--isolate the problem and continue from there. I'd also check the version of Struts and see if there are any known compatibility issues.

Comment: So I have narrowed the issue down to where I have <html:form action="Login">. I am guessing that it has an issue with where I use my action. I get an error when I add that html tag and also where I have html:text property="username" maxlength="32" size="20" /> because I think that requires the action to be working.

Comment: The html tags require a (1) backing action, and most (all?) require (2) a working `ActionForm`. I'd still see if you can get a complete-enough stack trace to see where the SO error begins--I can't think of anything off the top of my head that would cause an SO just because of updating to 1.8, but S1 was written long, *long* before 1.8 existed, so it's hard to say.